# LWJGL Display.create() does nothing on mac

Tags: opengl, awt, lwjgl

On Linux, Display.create() works wonderfully.  On Mac, the function call never returns, and does not throw an error.  What could cause this?  Is it because I'm adding it to a java.awt.Canvas?  if so, why has that worked before?

edit:
    This only happens when LWJGL is embedded in a canvas in swing *and* is running on a thread separate from the swing thread.

Comment: I recently was given a flash new Mac for work and have been testing my LWJGL-based engine and various demos on it, all works fine.  This is a brand new machine with (presumably) up-to-date drivers and so on though. What machine are you testing on? what version of LWJGL? Java? etc.

Comment: Also, can you provide a cut-down application that fails on your machine so others can try and replicate?  Otherwise it's just going to be guesswork and you won't get much help.

Comment: It was tested on at least three new-ish macbooks (maverics).  I'll edit to clarify that LWJGL was running embedded in an awt canvas embedded in swing running on a thread separate from the swing thread.

Comment: Actually, I left a lot out.  If I kept it on the swing thread, it still worked.  If I didn't embed it in swing it still worked.  My application had some crazy requirements.